# Increasing "MaxStringContentLength" for connecting to webservice

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I'm connecting to a webservice with the following code:

```
            Dim wsRemote As New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://www.exampleurl.com/example.asmx")
            Dim wsBinding As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding = Nothing
            Dim wsListenerBindingClass As Type = Nothing
            wsListenerBindingClass = GetType(System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding)
            wsBinding = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(wsListenerBindingClass), System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding)
            Dim m_wsTest As wsExample.WebServiceSoapClient = New wsExample.WebServiceSoapClient(wsBinding, wsRemote)
```

The m_wsTest class instance provides several methods for retrieving xml string based information. If the total string size exceeds 8192 (default) then I (obviously) get the following error message:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter Test.ExampleWebservice:GetInfoResponse. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Test.ExampleWebservice.wsTest.GetInfoResponseBody. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 12760.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

I understand what this error message means and what I have to do (increase quota), but simply cannot find ou where and how to do this. So, I need you help with this.

NB: I don't want to include the ".exe.config" file in the installation. I want the connection without it, just via code.

NB: I understand C# and VB.NET, so code examples may be in either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize ReaderQuotas with the required length and assign it to binding.

```
        var readerqts = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        readerqts.MaxStringContentLength = 20000;           
        wsListenerBindingClass.ReaderQuotas = readerqts;
```

Alternatively if you are using [HTTPWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength.aspx) to get through WebService you can use,

```
      HTTPWebRequest.ContentLength = 10000;
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how/where to include this in my code example?

Comment: edited have a look, but to clear up, reader quotas are assigned to httpbinding instance.

Comment: Many many thanks, I was struggling from five hours with this problem, tried to add everything in app.config but nothing worked. This solution worked when you assign the same setting from code-behind. I am still wondering why same settings worked from code-behind but not from app.config.